# How to play .wav file by using Audio Queues in Iphone sdk

Tags: nstimer, core-audio, audioqueue, audio-player

I am new to ios application development, Now I am working on a musical project in which i need accurate timings.So i have decided to use Audio Queue API to play my sound file present in the main bundle that is of .wav format, Its been 2 weeks i am struggling with this, Can anybody please help me out of this problem.

If any body send me some sample code for this then it would be a great help for me.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Apple's SpeakHere sample app shows how use the Audio Queue API for recording and playing.